Классы vs функции. Когда и что использовать?
Пишу на Python. Перешёл на него с C#, и старался поменять только классы. Но понимаю, что это гиблое дело, когда можно гибко применять как классы, так и функции вместе. И вот вопрос. Правильно я понимаю, чтобы код был лёгок в поддержке, масштабировании и читаемости, то в Python мы используем классы, если у нас есть какие-то структуры данных или сущности с состоянием, а в остальном мы всегда используем функции, которые будут использовать данные сущности в виде объектов?

Да, примерно так. Классы нужны когда нужно хранить состояние или есть набор одних и тех же параметров, которые нужно постоянно использовать в нескольких функциях. Ну или для группировки данных без дополнительных методов - например датакласс или NamedTuple. В остальных случаях - достаточно просто функций.

Классы в Питоне - это не инструмент удобства кодирования, наследования и быстрого и понятного создания визуального проектирования. Это ещё один гемор, применяемый почему-то там, где надо и не надо. Часто вижу программы, состоящие из одного скриптика разнесчастного, но классов там понапихано, как будто это постоянно используемый объект написанного ядра функций многократного использования. Классы в большинстве случаев работают паблик-переменными. Всё это удобно в визуальных средах проектирования, но в Питоне такие среды - сами по себе языки (пример PyQt). А в книжках об этом дурдом.

Я программировал в Visual FoxPro раньше. Вот там классы - это то, что облегчает жизнь, делает код быстро изменяемым, удобным, коротким и понятным. Среда разработки сделана именно для этого. Можно быстро создать свои базовые классы в визуальной среде, хорошо их отладить, а потом использовать для создания реальных объектов в программах. В Питоне это надо писать ручками и вдесятеро дольше.

Начните с функций и структур  - это минимальный набор средств. Если вокруг определённой структуры накапливаются функции, которые с ней работают, их разумно собрать в класс.

Вот статья про то, когда не стоит использовать классы: https://habr.com/ru/articles/140581/.
